# The intersection of all events in a sequence has probability $\lim \limits _{k \to \infty} P(A_k)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

If a sequence $A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots$ of events is decreasing, show that the intersection of all events in the sequence has probability: $\lim \limits _{k \to \infty} P(A_k)$.

I suck at proofs so I am lost. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $A_1\supset \cdots \supset A_{n}\cdots$, we have
$$
A_1=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\cup \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}(A_{n-1}-A_n)\tag1
$$
Note that
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\cap \bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}(A_{n-1}-A_n)=\varnothing
$$
Also $A_{n-1}-A_n$ are disjont. Moreover since $A_{n-1}\supset A_n$
$$
P(A_{n-1}-A_n)=P(A_{n-1})-P(A_{n})
$$
 So
\begin{align}
P(A_1)&=P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}P(A_{n-1}-A_{n})
\\
&=P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(P(A_{n-1})-P(A_{n}))
\\
&=P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n}(P(A_{k-1})-P(A_{k}))
\\
&=P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)+\lim_{n\to\infty}(P(A_{1})-P(A_{n}))
\\
&=P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)+P(A_{1})-\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_{n})
\end{align}
Hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_{n})=P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)
$$